# My raspberry pi 2 model B boots but then the screen turns black

Tags: boot-issues

It has been a while since I have last used my raspberry pi 2 model B. When turned on its power strip it started to boot and the code was running down the screen but all of a sudden the screen turned black. I could tell that the screen was still on but just a black set. So naturally I turned to the internet for help. Someone else had a similar problem. Their problem was solved when they wiggled the mouse and pressed some buttons on their keyboard and then pressed Alt and F1. When I attempted this my screen flashed a long column of words that were not code but it had something to do with the fact that there wasn't a warranty. Every time I pressed Alt and F1 this screen would flash but my problem was never fully solved. Please help, I would like to get back to coding. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please tell us what operating system you are using? Have you tried formatting the SD card, or using a different SD card?

Answer (score 0):

How long has it been? It could be because your software is outdated.

Once you get to the black screen, try pressing [CTRL+ALT+F1]. This should bring you to the hard terminal. Log in like normal and update and upgrade your Pi using {sudo apt-get update} and {sudo apt-get upgrade}.

This fixed my problems a long time ago when I had this problem.