# Model B (oldest) boots for a while, then screen goes black, then reboots. Using latest Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: boot-issues, pi-b

I have a Model B with 2 USB ports. From what I can tell this is the very first version. See picture below from when it was functioning long ago.

It was last used in 2014 with a then-current version of Raspbian, but I lost the memory card.

I recently tried to revive it so I bought a new memory card (SD adapter with 32 Gb micro-SD), downloaded and installed the current version of Raspberry Pi OS, and tried to boot up.

On the first boot, there was a message about generating SSH keys (I chose not to do that when creating the boot image).

Then a black screen with the Raspberry Pi logo and some file names passing by written below it. Looks like a normal boot. This goes on for 10-30 seconds. Then the monitor goes black, saying "no signal" as if the PI stopped sending video, and if I wait a couple of minutes, the PI reboots most of the time, repeating these things except the SSH part. Sometimes it just stays black.

I thought there might be some incompatibility between the newest OS and the oldest PI, but are there any other "obvious" suggestions than trying an older/lightweight OS?

I saw this thread which is somewhat related but not a duplicate:

[Lightweight OS for original Raspberry Pi Model B?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137036/lightweight-os-for-original-raspberry-pi-model-b)

Also saw this post suggesting to move mouse/press keyboard, which does not help in my case
[My raspberry pi 2 model B boots but then the screen turns black](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56459/my-raspberry-pi-2-model-b-boots-but-then-the-screen-turns-black)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I installed Legacy on the SD card and this works. Had some video problems which were surprisingly solved by **enabling** overscan (which was disabled), contrary to all suggestions I found.

Answer (score 1):

You provide very little info.

My guess would be an issue with your (unspecified) monitor. You might try some of the display settings in https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#hdmi-mode

Raspberry Pi OS SHOULD work on all Pi (I haven't tried on a model B).
Bullseye introduced some quite significant changes - particularly KMS which is configured differently to older models.

You might be better to try Legacy https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/new-old-functionality-with-raspberry-pi-os-legacy/